# Input and output for a simple keyword search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the Javascript and Jquery scene. I am trying to create a keyword search that when a button is clicked the phrase in the text box is given a specific answer in a text area. I have created two Arrays with keywords that I'm looking for but I don't know how to make the program look for the keyword and respond with an answer.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="AskAQuestion">

    <div id="questionsArea">
        <div class="questionAreaSpacing"><input type="text" name="questionTxt" id="questionTxt"></div>
        <textarea readonly id="answerArea">

        </textarea>

        <div class="questionAreaSpacing"><input type="submit" name="answerBtn" id="answerBtn" value="Click Me!"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the script:

```
<script>
var quesArr = ["redcom","google", "orange"];
var ansArr = ["test 1","test 2","test 3"];

function getAnswer(){ 
}; 


function answer(){
    if ($("#questionTxt").val().toLowerCase().string. == getAnswer()){
        $('#answerArea').html("");
    }
    else if($("#questionTxt").val() !=  getAnswer()){
        $('#answerArea').html('You didn\'t say the magic word');
    }
    else if($("#questionTxt").val() == "" ){
        $('#answerArea').html('what are you thinking');
    }
}; 

$("#answerBtn").click(function(){
    answer();
});


$("#questionTxt").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $("#answerBtn").click();
    }
});

</script>
```

Please help me I want to learn how to do this badly :(

Comment: you just fire your event on onkeypress event & call this function

Comment: Syntax error on this line: `if ($("#questionTxt").val().toLowerCase().string. == getAnswer()){`. remove the `.` after `string`.

Comment: that wasn't suppose to be in there. That was from another failed attempt on something else.....I'm having issues with what to do on the checking to see if the keyword is correct in the array and the spiting out the matching answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing the question into the function as a parameter. then loop through the `quesArr` to see if its present and print out the corresponding answer:

```
var quesArr = ["redcom","google", "orange"];
var ansArr = ["test 1","test 2","test 3"];

function getAnswer(question){ 
    var questionIsPresent = false;

    //loop through array to see if question is present
    for (var i = 0; i < quesArr.length; i++) {
        if(quesArr[i] === question){
              $('#answerArea').html(ansArr[i]); 
              questionIsPresent = true;
        }
    }

    if(questionIsPresent == false){
        $('#answerArea').html('You didn\'t say the magic word');
    }

    if(question == "" ){
        $('#answerArea').html('what are you thinking');
    }
}; 

 $("#answerBtn").click(function(){
    //pass in the question to the function
    getAnswer($("#questionTxt").val().toLowerCase());
 });

$("#questionTxt").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $("#answerBtn").click();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J2Vz3/)